# payment intent not changes status after processing

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, stripe-payment-intent

```
const reader = await stripe.terminal.readers.processPaymentIntent(
        'reader_id',
        { payment_intent:'payment_intent.id' }
);
```

I am integrating stripe terminal for collecting payment. I have created payment intent first and then I am processing that payment intent with processPaymentIntent API. I have read in stripe docs that after processing it changes status from 'requires_payment_method' to 'requires_capture' but in my case it is not changing status. Please guide me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After processPaymentIntent you will need to wait for customers to insert their card to the reader. Have you observed that step is done successfully? There are 4 approaches to observe:

1. Listen to webhooks
2. Poll the Stripe API
3. Use the PaymentIntent
4. Use the reader object

Refer to [Stripe Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/collect-payment?terminal-sdk-platform=server-driven#verify-reader) for more detail.